# Realm Flexible device sync while client is offline. (React native SDK)

Tags: react-native, expo, realm, atlas-device-sync

I have a scenario where I need the application user to be able to log in while online. After logging in, the sync should be paused on the client side. The user should then be able to use the app offline (without network connectivity), creating and updating documents locally for two or three days. When the offline period (the period during which the user is either offline or the user is online but the sync is disabled) ends or the user has completed all necessary updates, I should be able to resume the synchronization process.

Currently, I’ve configured the flexible sync as per the documentation, and the user is able to log in successfully. The synchronization appears to be working properly, with both pause and resume functions operational while online. However, when I turn off the network connection and restart the app while offline, the cached user remains present, and the local Realm database is functional, as I can observe documents being queried.

The issue arises when, after a few seconds or milliseconds, the app repeatedly throws the following error in the console:

``` [error] App: request location failed (CustomError -1): request to ``https://realm.mongodb.com/api/client/v2.0/app/*[app-id]*/location`` failed, reason: Network request failed ```

and the app components start re-rendering continuously.
**I don’t understand what am I missing or is it that way!**
**How can I be able to persist disabled sync on client across app restarts?**

Here is my AppWrapper:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { AppProvider, UserProvider, useApp } from '@realm/react';
import Realm from 'realm';

import { schemas } from '../../models';

import { RealmProvider } from '@realm/react';
import { OpenRealmBehaviorType, OpenRealmTimeOutBehavior, SyncError } from 'realm';
import { LoginScreen } from '../LoginScreen';
import SyncFallback from '../SyncFallback';

const AppWrapper: React.FC<{
    appId: string;
    children: React.ReactNode;
}> = ({ appId, children }) => {
    const [syncError, setSyncError] = useState<SyncError | null>(null);

    const realmAccessBehavior: Realm.OpenRealmBehaviorConfiguration = {
        type: OpenRealmBehaviorType.OpenImmediately,
        timeOutBehavior: OpenRealmTimeOutBehavior?.OpenLocalRealm ?? 'openLocalRealm',
        timeOut: 1000,
    };

    return (
        <AppProvider id={appId}>
            <UserProvider fallback={<LoginScreen />}>
                <RealmProvider
                    schema={schemas}
                    fallback={<SyncFallback err={syncError} />}
                    sync={{
                        flexible: true,
                        existingRealmFileBehavior: {
                            type: OpenRealmBehaviorType.OpenImmediately,
                        },
                        newRealmFileBehavior: realmAccessBehavior,
                    }}
                >
                    {children}
                </RealmProvider>
            </UserProvider>
        </AppProvider>
    );
};

export default AppWrapper;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question and desired outcome is a little vague. The comment in your code says "if we are logged in add the sync config" but that's not what the question says you want. You don't want sync, right?

Comment: @Jay,  The comment should not be there, is from my other implementation. My bad!. 
I want sync to work as described above.

Comment: Realm can be used online or offline pretty transparently. The initial user authentication requires the app to be be online, but after that, if the network connection is interrupted (for example), Realm will use the cached user. Additionally it will just 'connect' to the local Realm when offline. However, I believe the downloadBeforeOpen must be OFF, which is part of Config.

Comment: @Jay, as you can see, I have set the "existingRealmFileBehavior: {
                            type: OpenRealmBehaviorType.OpenImmediately,
                        },"
to open immediately.
"downlodBeforeOpen" is OFF, why do I get the error as mentioned on restarting the app offline.
Please go through the question again.

Comment: Hmm. See [Access a Synced Realm While Offline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/sync-data/configure-a-synced-realm/#access-a-synced-realm-while-offline) note that if a timeout behavior is specified, implement `type: 'downloadBeforeOpen',` as shown [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/sync-data/configure-a-synced-realm/#access-after-timeout-with-background-sync). I think opening immediately is in confict with a timeout "where it's uncertain if the user has an Internet connection". Is this something that just starting happening or has it never worked?

Comment: It never worked, it seems to me that flexible sync always tries to connect to the server irrespective of the sync config, even pausing and resuming sync is uncontrollable on the client. Tried every possible configuration. 
[Access a Synced Realm While Offline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/sync-data/configure-a-synced-realm/#access-a-synced-realm-while-offline) is not comprehensive at all.
**After all thanks for being there.**
I'm confused, what to do?